# Classloaders and duplicate package and class names

Tags: java, android, maven, classloader

I'm using AndroidStudio with maven. what i don't understand is how duplicate classes don't confuse classloaders nor the build process.

I made my own `android.util.Log` class (like, i made a `android.util` package inside my app, and inside it i made my own `Log` class), instead of using the standard android `Log.d`, i use my own. How and why does this work?

i've read somewhere that there are 3 classloaders - your application classloader, 3rd party libs classloader, and system classloaders. so is it that they go in some kind of priority, where if your application classloader finds the .class file then it gets "linked"? and any other duplicate .class files just don't matter?

and... why isn't this behaviour causing any kind of build errors/warnings?

an example is that ... say i want to use reflection to call a certain private class that both i and android will provide. i want guarantee that whether or not it calls mine or ANdroid's, there's not clash that causes a crash. but i'd like to know exactly why/how it works the way i'm seeing it work.

Answer (score 0):

ClassLoaders are organized in a hierarchy:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/beadf/index.html

This may point to what you're looking for:
http://yenliangl.blogspot.fr/2009/11/dynamic-loading-of-classes-in-your.html